# Spring 3.2 / Hibernate4.1.9 : Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm getting crazy right now about a small piece of code.
I'm creating a simpel rest service based on the spring MVC 3.2 and using a JPA persistence layer with spring-orm and hibernate4.1.9.

I'm facing a curious bug concerning an unmapped class. Here is my first entity (works perfectly before I set up relationship)

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {
//[...]
@OneToMany(mappedBy="owner", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<FileInfo> fileInfos;
//[...]
}
```

**FileInfo.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="file_info")
public class FileInfo {
//[...]
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "owner_id")
private User owner;
//[...]
}
```

**Servlet config**

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--[...]-->
<context:component-scan base-package="org.mypackage.myapp" />
<!--[...]-->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
   class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
   <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
   <property name="configLocation">
      <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
   </property>
   <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.mypackage.myapp.model" />
   <property name="configurationClass">
      <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
   </property>
   <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <props>
         <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
         <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
      </props>
   </property>
</bean>
<!--[...]-->
<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean id="transactionManager"
   class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
   <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
<!--[...]-->
```

**Bug trace**

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: org.mypackage.myapp.model.User.fileInfos[org.mypackage.myapp.model.FileInfo]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindManyToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1057)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:733)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:668)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1597)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1355)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1737)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1788)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:242)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:372)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:357)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483)
```

Is anybody knows where is the problem. I don't have a lot of experience with this technology, and I'm not sure that information provided in this post are sufficient.

Thanks for help !

EDIT :

Here is my hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <mapping package="org.mypackage.myapp.model"/>
    <mapping class="org.mypackage.myapp.model.User"/>
    <mapping class="org.mypackage.myapp.model.FileInfo"/>
    <mapping class="org.mypackage.myapp.model.Group"/>
    <mapping class="org.mypackage.myapp.model.FileInfoGroup"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

ollie314

Comment: What's the fully qualified name of the Entity annotation used in FileInfo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK,
I'm finally find out why the application generated a bug during the deployment !.

I probably made an error during configuration process. I'm configuring a spring-servlet file and dont see I also have another configuration file in my spring configuration folder named root-context.xml. It has been auto generated by STS during my project configuration (probably due to a bad manipulation from me) and this is the file used by the server to deploy the application. In this file, my session factory bean wasn't correctly configured. So, after fix errors, everythings works perfectly.

*Note : I'm not sure about the necessity of the hibernate.cfg.xml with spring since everything could be made in the root spring configuration file. In my mind, it is only necessary when a project define many times a session factory. According to a DRY pattern, hibernate.cfg,xml is relevant in this situation. Anybody can tell me if I'm wrong please ?*

Comment: As per the configuration you have , hibernate.cfg.xml is necessary , one alternate way is to move all the hibernate configuration directly to `hibernateProperties`

Comment: Ok.thanks a lot for this comment. Very helpfull to understand the process workflow !